# Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring Batch and connecting to Oracle 12c instance.

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

And I am getting the below error :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:619)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:781)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:284)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:98)
    at CustomerFileGenerationMain.main(CustomerFileGenerationMain.java:28)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol
```

Spring Batch xml file

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="username" value="MY_OWNER"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1527/myCloud" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="ORACLE" />
</bean>
```

and pom.xml file - 
Only this dependency I used

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

I tried below as well..

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Please guide how to convert below code to XML bean ?**

```
@Bean(name = "DataSource")
    public DataSource batchDataSource() throws IOException {    
        OracleDataSource ds = null;
        MCUserInfoFactory userInfoFactory = new MCUserInfoFactory();
        try {
            MCUserInfo userInfo = userInfoFactory.getMCUserInfo(XXXXLabel);
            if (userInfo != null) {
                ds = getDataSource(userInfo, edsurl);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return ds;
    }
```

I am using the following version -

```
/:/oracle/home $ sqlplus / as sysdba
-bash: sqlplus: command not found
/:/oracle/home $ . ~/.profile
/:/oracle/home $ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Jun 28 01:56:56 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options
```

Answer (score 0):

Check driver file(.jar) version and ORACLE db version you are using is compatible with each other,
usually that causes this issue.

Comment: Could you please call out that Oracle Driver class name ?

Comment: Check out the JDBC FAQ (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1) for more details on the JDBC driver version and the JDK that it is compatible with. Always, try to use the latest JDBC driver. It is backward compatible with lower version of the database.

Comment: @Nirmala Thanks for providing link , I think that will solve the issues